# Symbolic links for video files doesn't play the video

Tags: video, symbolic-link

Dear Folks,

```
ln -sn Videos/vfile.mp4  Documents/Symlink/
```

creates a symbolic link but I couldn't play the video using vlc.
What is the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an absolute path for the target file (the video, in this case).
Try this instead:

```
ln -sn /home/$USER/Videos/vfile.mp4 Documents/Symlink/
```

Also ~/Videos/vfile.mp4 would work because '~' evaluates to /home/$USER.